# trigonometry problem with powers

Tags: trigonometry

I don't think I fully understand what the difference between for example $\cos^2 x$ and $\cos x^2$.
Example question: how to solve $2\cos^3x-5\cos^2x-3\cos x=0$ for $x\in (-180,180]$ degrees.

Comment: By convention, $cos^2 x$ is taken to mean $cos(x)^2 = cos(x)cos(x)$. If you want to put the square on x write $cos(x^2)$.

Comment: To add to and reformat @Paul's explanation: by convention. $\cos^2 x = [\cos x]^2$. So, for example, with $x = 45^\circ$: $\cos^2 (45) = (\cos 45 )^2 = (1/\sqrt 2)^2 = 1/2$, whereas $\cos (45^2) = \cos 2025 =-1/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: If you are asking for a solution to the example question, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The plots below are those of $(\cos(x))^2$ and $\cos(x^2)$. Try to figure out which is which.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets to format these expressions clearly and unambiguously. Then you can distinguish between $\cos^2(x)$, which is the square of the cosine of $x$, and $\cos(x^2)$, which is the cosine of the square of $x$.

If the equation you are trying to solve is

$2 \cos^3(x) - 5\cos^2(x) -3\cos(x)=0$

then start by replacing $\cos(x)$ by $y$ to get:

$2y^3 - 5y^2 - 3y=0$

One solution is clearly $y=0$, which gives you $\cos(x)=0$ and so $x=\pm 90^o$. The other two solutions are the roots of the quadratic equation

$2y^2 - 5y - 3=0$

Solve this quadratic to find its roots $y_1, y_2$, then find the values of $x$ for which $\cos(x)=y_1$ and $\cos(x)=y_2$.

Comment: This answer seems to be going into too much detail about the homework-like question, which shows no effort, rather than the question about notation.